# Drawing perpendicular lines to a curved path in tikz-pgf without decorations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, tikz-path

I'm trying to make a image like this:

[image]

Here's how I'm CURRENTLY doing it:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[color=black, line width=2pt, -latex] (-3,2.5) -- (0, 2.5) +(0,\rad) coordinate (center) (0,2.5) arc[start angle=270, delta angle=30, radius=\rad];
    \foreach \a in {270, 280, 290}{
        \draw[draw=blue,-latex,thick] (center) ++(\a:\rad) -- +(\a-180:1cm) node at +(\a-180:1.5cm) {$F_m$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Where \rad is just a given radius I defined. Currently this makes a dummy coordinate at the center of the "circle." This also means that Tikz makes a very large border with a lot of extra white space, and I'm trying to look for a solution that may eliminate this dummy variable or whitespace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest doing this with `pic`s, which are "little tikz pictures" inside tikz pictures. Note: you should **never** put a tikz picture inside another tikz picture. The `pic` construction is designed to avoid that situation.

Here we will design a `pic` in the shape of a blue arrow pointing up from `(0,0)`, with a node above it containing the label. The same commands to make a `tikzpicture` are used in the `pic`. When we place the `pic` on a line or curve, `(0,0)` corresponds to the location on the segment. With the `sloped` option, it will adjust its coordinates so "up" is perpendicular to the segment.

[image]

The `pic` is named `perp`, and can be called at any point on a segment with the usage

`...to pic[pos=<pct>,sloped]{perp=<label text>}(x,y)`

where `<pct>` is the percentage along the current segment and `<label text>` is processed in math mode.

The `pic` is defined with `tikzset` in the preamble. I have the length set to `.7`cm, with the label 3mm above it at `(0,1)` (in the perpendicular coordinate system).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{perp/.pic={\draw[blue,-latex,thick](0,0)--(0,.7); 
    \node[text=black, font=\scriptsize] at(0,1){$#1$};},
    perp/.default={}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick](0,0)to pic[sloped]{perp}(2,0)
    to[out=0,in=-120] pic[pos=.3,sloped]{perp=F_m} pic[pos=.8,sloped]{perp=F_m}(4,1);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that to use `pic` with `arc`, you must use the "long form" of the arc command:

`\draw[thick](0,0) arc[start angle=120,end angle=60,radius=2] pic[pos=.8,sloped]{perp=F_m};`

[image]

Comment: Very nice (and simple) implementation +1

Answer (score 8):

While you are waiting for tikz support, here is a version in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html), showing the useful `direction .. of` construct, which gives you a `pair` representing the direction at a particular time along the path.

[image]

Compile this with `lualatex`...

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path ramp;
    ramp = origin -- 100 right {right}.. 300 right rotated 12;

    for t = 0.9, 1.3, 1.7:
        path a;
        a = (origin -- 72 up) 
            rotated angle direction t of ramp
            shifted point t of ramp;
        drawarrow subpath(0, 0.8) of a withcolor 2/3 blue;
        label("$F_m$", point 1 of a);
    endfor

    drawarrow ramp withpen pencircle scaled 1;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an Asymptote way.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);
path p=(0,0) .. controls (3,.5) and (5,-3) .. (8,2);
real[] t={.3,.45,.65,.8,.9};
string[] Lt={"$F_a$","$F_b$","$F_c$","$F_d$","$F_e$"};
for(int i=0; i<t.length; ++i){
pair M=point(p,t[i]);       // before I was confusing with M=relpoint(p,t[i]);
pair Mn=rotate(90)*dir(p,t[i]);
draw(Label(Lt[i],EndPoint),M--M+.8Mn,blue,Arrow(TeXHead));
}

draw(p,magenta+1pt,Arrow);
```

Comment: @YvanVelenik Sorry! I was confusing `relpoint` and `point`. Corrected!

Comment: +1 for `point` instead of `relpoint`.